# What should I modify to add a new field in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to make "channel" available in the next html form. But I don't know how. Can you help me?

models.py

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=100)
    # 1(User 진행자) : N(Channel)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vod_owner_channels', verbose_name=_('User'))
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'), max_length=1000, blank=True)
    background_image = models.ImageField(_('Background Image'), upload_to='background_image/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Channel Create Date'), auto_now_add=True)


class Video(models.Model):
    # 1(Channel) : N(Video)
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vod_channel_videos', verbose_name=_('Channel'))
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'), max_length=1000, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(_('Video'), upload_to='video/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    video_url = models.URLField(_('Video URL'), blank=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Views'), default=0)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Create Date'), auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Update date'), auto_now=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    # 1(User) : N(Comment)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vod_user_comments', verbose_name=_('Comment'))
    # 1(Video) : N(Comment)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vod_video_comments', verbose_name=_('Video'))
    content = models.TextField(_('Content'), max_length=1000)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Create Date'), auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Update date'), auto_now=True)

    reply = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vod_reply_comments', verbose_name=_('Reply'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Comment')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Comments')
```

serializers.py

```
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    channel = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='channel.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ['id', 'channel', 'title', 'description', 'video',
                  'video_url', 'views', 'create_date', 'update_date']
```

I tried to make serializers.PrimaryRelatedKey.
But it didn't work.
I think, I can solve this problem in this code. but I don't have confidence.

views.py

```
# VodCreate : /vod/new
class VodCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request):
        return Response()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a serializer for your Channel model and pass it to your VideoSerializer like this:

```
channel= ChannelSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
```

many arg can be True depend on your use case.

Comment: channel = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Channel.objects.all())